# Angular2 TestBed can't find nested provider without @Inject

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, karma-runner

I have the following service I want to test:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import DepA from "./dep-a"

@Injectable()
export default class TestService {
    private readonly DepA: DepA;

    public constructor(depA: DepA) {
        this.DepA = depA;
    }
}
```

It is dependant on another service called DepA:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export default class DepA {
}
```

I now want to create a unit test for TestService with the following:

```
import { async, inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import DepA from "./dep-a";
import TestService from "./test-service";

class MockDepA {
}

describe("TestService", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        let dep = new DepA();

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                TestService,
                { provide: DepA, useValue: dep },
            ]
        });
    });

    it('should construct', inject(
        [TestService], (testService: TestService) => {
            expect(testService).toBeDefined();
        }));
});
```

This gives me the following error:

```
$ ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 10 0.0.0) TestService should construct FAILED
        Error: Can't resolve all parameters for TestService: (?).
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.033 secs / 0.021 secs)
```

When I change the constructor of TestService from `public constructor(depA: DepA) {` to `public constructor(@Inject(DepA) depA: DepA) {` it seems to work fine. Is there any reason why I have to annotate my injections with `@Inject()` in my unit tests, but it works just fine under normal circumstances without?

Comment: I've checked your code, and it works fine for me with the latest version of ng-cli.

Comment: I've also retested my code on the quick-start seed (https://github.com/angular/quickstart), and it seems to indeed work perfectly. I therefore think that the issue is a configuration file issue. The issue most likely lies with the fact that I use webpack; I seriously need to set up different production and release environments. I'll put the answer here in case I've figured it out. My karma.conf.js can be found at http://pastebin.com/prcnsjVR, and my webpack.conf.js at http://pastebin.com/T28GJMGN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the answer people are looking for; but I rewrote my debug environment such that the output is now a multitude of .spec.js files, instead of using a Karma Typescript Pre-processor. I'm not sure why it didn't work; only that this way it *does* work for me.